# What is X-Cache:MISS from localhost and X-Cache-Lookup:MISS from localhost:3128

Tags: php, ajax, apache, rest, response-headers

I'm seeing these two headers in my response header of an AJAX call. Need to know more about this and what is the meaning of this header? Is this implies to caching of data from server?

```
X-Cache:MISS from localhost 
X-Cache-Lookup:MISS from localhost:3128
```

Comment: i don't want to copy paste, but recommend you to look through these articles
1. https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/CacheDigests
2. https://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2008/04/22/x-cache-and-x-cache-lookup-headers-explained/